# How to get an output from an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Ok so I have been learning javascript and I know most basic things but I would like to know how to get an output from an array based on text in another array...

For example:

```
var input = ["hi", "welcome"];  
var output = ["hello", "thank you"];
```

So if I were to input "hi" i would like the return to be "hello" the same for "welcome" and "thank you".

or `input[0] = output[0]` but I would like to search the input array and then get the output string for the input.

possibly a for statement? I have been trying to find different ways, but there may be someone out there who might know how to do this!

I appreciate any help I get!

Edit:
To clarify, if anyone has worked with IRC, its what I am working with, so I would need to check the messages and compare them to an input array or object and then output the string in another array or the matching key in an object.

Comment: Find the index of the value in `input` and use that index to access `output`.

Comment: What @FelixKling said. `var key = input.indexOf("hi");` then... `var outputVal = output[key];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FelixKling stated, `indexOf` will work. You don't always want to take approaches like this, however, especially if you have large arrays. The reason why is that `indexOf` will traverse the array to find the match, and if there's a large array that could take a while. In "big O", the operation is `O(n)`.

Generally if you want lookups, you should use a JavaScript object, which gives you `O(1)` complexity:

```
var outputForInput = {
  "hi": "hello",
  "welcome": "thank you"
};

var input = "hi";
var output = outputForInput[input];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions.

The first would be to use an object:

```
var obj = {"hi":"hello","welcome":"thank you"}
```

and access the data in the following way:

```
obj["hi"]; //returns hello
obj["welcome"]; //returns thank you
```

You can use the [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function to get an array of the keys.

To do the same thing with arrays, use the native [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function. Given your arrays, the code would be:

```
output[input.indexOf("hi")] //returns hello
```

The problem with this method is that indexOf returns -1 if the query string does not exist in the array. This will cause an error to be thrown whereas obj["nonexistantkey"] simply returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

By testing for the value in a loop, you will get the index, which you can use to return that same spot on your output Array.

```
function inOut(a1, val, a2){
  for(var i=0,l=a1.length; i<l; i++){
    if(a1[i] === val){
      return a2[i];
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(inOut(input, 'hi', output)); // returns 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getResponse(inputStr){
    return output[input.indexOf(inputStr)];
}
```

Or if you follow Jacob's advice (which I recommend):

```
function getResponse(inputStr){
    return outputForInput[inputStr];
}
```

Note that either of these will return `undefined` if there is no match for the input string.